# Cannot get antd Select Tags to be draggable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I need to drag and drop tags from one Select to another, and for that I'm going to use http://react-dnd.github.io.

I tried to make it work but so far I couldn't. I believe that's because my component inside the tag is not firing the "dragstart" event.

You can replicate the problem here on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/m5kz2vw5p

I tried debugging to find out why `dragstart` is not getting fired but I ran out of ideas.

Do you have any ideas on how this could work?

Comment: Maybe some css from ant is blocking it ?

Comment: @DusanJovanov I tried changing and removing css but so far I couldn't find anything that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

You should add this event to your Tag label:

```
onMouseDown={e => {e.stopPropagation();}}
```

The complete solution can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6yn1qp7wnn